# Nginx give error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when accessing website from outside network

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to deploy my laravel app to ubuntu using nginx, everything was fine before I using ssl. But after I using ssl, it's not working anymore if I'm accessing my website using outside network (still working if I access it using server network).

this is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    server_name kopidw.id www.kopidw.id;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate_kopinedw.crt; #path to your public key
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/private_kopinedw.key; #path to your private key
    ssl_client_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/ca-bundle.crt;
    ssl_verify_client   optional;

    root /var/www/html/kopinedw-cms/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

This is my first time using nginx, so I don't have any Idea why I got `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Any help would be very helpful for me, thanks

Comment: Suspect that your Laravel app might be redirecting back to HTTP. Could you updated question with some config, specifically `APP_URL`?

Comment: @jhmckimm `APP_URL=https://kopidw.id` inside my .env

Comment: Did you open port 443 on your server?

Comment: @programandoconro My ufw is inactive